# how to pass data in Highcharts(Line Graph)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to draw a [Line Graph with irregular Time interval](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time). I want to pass the data to it via my Ajax calls. How do I do it?

My data is of the following format-

result =     `{u'New Delhi': [[1383741000000L, 54.2], [1383741900000L, 59.34], [1383742800000L, 64.3]], u'Bangalore': [[1383741000000L, 1608.2], [1383741900000L, 1611.3], [1383742800000L, 1612.29]]}`

ie

result =     `{'name1':[[time1(in secs), value1][time1(in secs), value1]], 'name2':[[time1(in secs), value1][time2(in secs), value2]] }`

as in like this.

```
series: [{
    name: result.keys(),
    data: result.values()
}]
```

I should get two lines and thier respective values.

How do I pass my values to the data.?

Answer (score 2):

Data for Highcharts can be a key value pair. You need to tweak your AJAX response object in your JS. I feel that you should do something like this (if you have any array of cities):

```
series = [];
for(var i in cities)    {  
    var values = [];
    for(var pair in result[cities[i]])   {
        values.push(result[cities[i][pair]);
    }
    series[i] = { "name" : cities[i], "value": values};
}
```

'cities' is an array of all the cities that you get in the AJAX response.
 You can use the following code to extract all the cities from your response:

```
var cities = [];
$.each(result, function(index, data) {
    cities.push(index)
});
```

Comment: Please explain. What is cities over here? I'm getting the response from AJAX which is saved in result variable.

Comment: I mean the variable cities in your solution.

Comment: @prafulbagai, cities is an array which contains all the cities like,'bangalore', 'mumbai'.
`var cities = ['New Delhi', 'Bangalore'];`

Comment: Can you please provide a jsFiddle Demo. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Nagkumar- See this http://jsfiddle.net/5yzb2/4/. I'm not able to get the line data in this. Please suggest where I'm wrong?

Comment: @prafulbagai, i'm sorry, I haven't used multi-charts. I'm looking at them now. I'll get back as soon as I learn this.